# Create Unix-like aliases in Django (Postgres) dbshell?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, shell

I open Django's database shell (dbshell) to access my PostgreSQL database quite frequently and find myself having to enter commands such as this one over and over:

```
 truncate <table> restart identity cascade;
```

Once I issue that command the first time, I can hit ^p to find it in my console history to run again but I'm wondering if there's any way to create an alias that that I could run inside the db shell to run this command?  I wouldn't mind running it from an external file either so long as the command wasn't as long as the command I'm trying to replace.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `dbshell` command would give you a database shell that you specified in your `settings.py`, so whatever command you run thereafter is database specific, thus it has nothing to do with django, right?

Comment: @ShangWang That's right, it's a simple abstraction to connect to your database-specific shell using the credentials from your settings.

Comment: So your question boils down to whether your database system shell supports aliasing. You need to edit your question to show people what database you are using.

Comment: You're right.  I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  To create an alias "trunctable", type this in the psql console or put the command in your .psqlrc file:

```
\set trunctable 'TRUNCATE mytable CASCADE;'
```

Then run the command inside your psql console like this:

```
:trunctable
```